# Jquery string to date conversion

Tags: jquery

I have a string '28-Dec-14' in a variable.I need to convert this string to date format.
my code is

```
<body>
<input type="text" id="from" readonly="" />
<input type="text" id="to" readonly="" onchange="checkDate(this);"/>
</body>
```

here date selected by uidatepicker

my script is

```
function checkDate(obj)
{
var from = $('#from').val();
var to = obj.value;
alert(to);
var date = to.split("-")[0],
          month = to.split("-")[1],
          year = to.split("-")[2];
var d = new Date (year,month,date );
alert(d);
}
```

here `year=14,month=Dec,and date=28`

Comment: you can use date.js jquery plugin to accomplish your task.

Answer (score 1):

No need to reinvent the wheel

```
 var date = new Date('28-Dec-14')
```

Comment: not a valid cross browser date format. For example will return `invalid date` in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
var d = new Date (year,months[month],date );
```

Comment: you are missing double quote after jun.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript's Date constructor to achieve this, just pass your date string to it;

```
new Date(yourString);
```

I have modified some of your code, assuming you are using JQuery, here is a working demo:

**[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m8epzLyg/)**

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are trying to validate a range and it'd be pretty easy, I'd just use momentjs (http://momentjs.com/).  Something like this - the fiddle has more actual details.  Even better if you are using jquery ui, it already has a date range that enforces to is after from http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

```
function isDateRangeValid(date1, date2) {
    var m1 = new moment(date1);
    var m2 = new moment(date2);

    if (m1.isValid() && m2.isValid()) {
        return m1 < m2;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

// Test the function
var testRanges = [
    ['01/10/2014','28-Dec-14'],
    ['28-Dec-2014', '27-Dec-14'],
    ['28-Dec-2014', '12/29/2014']
];

testRanges.forEach(function(entry) {
    alert('Range: ' + entry[0] + ' TO ' + entry[1] + 
      ', ISVALID: ' + 
      isDateRangeValid(entry[0],entry[1])
    );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8e9j7k7v/